# Trying to use break to get out of for loop after getting the desired value - always throwing an exception

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a for loop I'm using to iterate through an arraylist, and once I find the object I need I want to set a previously obtained object in a set method for this object, set a flag for 'not found' to false and then break out of the loop. After that I want to throw an exception if the not found flag is still true, otherwise just come to the end of the method.

I think I'm either misusing the break or the for loop. I am constantly getting the exception thrown.

Note, 'items' is the arraylist of LibraryItems.

```
        for(LibraryItem l : items) {
        if(l.equals(item)) {
            l.setCheckedOut(patronToRetrieve);
            itemNotFound = false;
            break;
        } else {
            itemNotFound = true;
        }
    }
        if (itemNotFound = true) {
            throw new CheckInOutException("The item " + item.getTitle() + " does not exist in the catalogue. Sorry, " + patronToRetrieve.getName() + ", you will not be able to check this out at this time.");
        } else {

        }
```

Comment: I believe you don't mean if (itemNotFound = true)  use ==

Comment: have you overriden `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing == not = for the if test

Comment: @Matt8541 Yeah I was being a dummy with the = instead of ==

Comment: @Matt8541 itemNotFound is boolen then why this double check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One issue I could see is:

```
if (itemNotFound = true) {
            throw new CheckInOutException("The item " + item.getTitle() + " does not exist in the catalogue. Sorry, " + patronToRetrieve.getName() + ", you will not be able to check this out at this time.");
        }
```

Above statement always results in `true`, because you are assigning `true` to `itemNotFound` in if clause.

should be:

```
if (itemNotFound) {
            throw new CheckInOutException("The item " + item.getTitle() + " does not exist in the catalogue. Sorry, " + patronToRetrieve.getName() + ", you will not be able to check this out at this time.");
        }
```

(or)

```
 if (itemNotFound == true) {
                throw new CheckInOutException("The item " + item.getTitle() + " does not exist in the catalogue. Sorry, " + patronToRetrieve.getName() + ", you will not be able to check this out at this time.");
            }
```

`==` is eqaulity check, `=` is assignment.

Comment: If itemNotFound is a boolean you will already have value either true/fase, then doing true==true is redundant check, nothing more than that I know of.